# If this is on, this isn't, but if this is, this isn't

Tags: java, if-statement

```
if(Camb.killaura){
    Camb.vkillaura = false;
}

if(Camb.vkillaura){
    Camb.killaura = false;
}
```

I'm making a modded client for a game called Minecraft. There are two types of kill aura, one that works on some servers and one that works on the others. Let's say I have VKillaura on, and I want to use KillAura instead, I'll press a button and they'll switch. This works. However, if I'm using KillAura and I want to switch to VKillAura, it won't let me. I think this is because Eclipse is reading from top to bottom, and my VKillaura if statement is below my kill aura one. How do I fix this?

Comment: @David. Please see clearly, he's not setting the same variable to false in `if` conditionals.

Comment: That headline is incredibly confusing.

Comment: @RohitJain: Ah, you're right.  More meaningful variable names would make that a *lot* more obvious.  (And probably make the intended logic a lot easier to implement/debug/maintain/etc.)

Comment: i think without more context about where this code is being called and what is looking at the `Camb` object, you won't get very helpful responses.

Comment: Am I high or the title is confusing?

Answer (score 8):

If I'm understanding you correctly, which is potentially somewhat of a stretch, you don't really need to worry about the present state when you press the toggle button (assuming you know you've initialised it correctly). You can simply toggle both auras. Of course, you'll need to initialise them correctly to start with, if that's impractical you'll need to use a different solution.

```
// When toggle aura button is pressed, toggle both auras to switch.
Camb.vkillaura = !Camb.vkillaura
Camb.killaura = !Camb.killaura
```

If you for whatever reason need to deal with it fully (e.g. there are more options added later), you can try the following approach:

```
if (Camb.killaura) {
    Camb.killaura = false;
    Camb.vkillaura = true;
} else if (Camb.vkillaura) {
    Camb.vkillaura = false;
    Camb.killaura = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I made it so when the key to turn one of the booleans to true, the other is turned to false.

Comment: +1 for 2nd answer... made it simple :)

Answer (score 1):

If one is always on and *thus* the other is off, you can also use *one* boolean flag.

Comment: Or, for extensibility and readability, an enum.